# Retrieve JSON return from PHP called from AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to call an PHP file via POST and retrieve its result back in the calling AJAX code. But unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. After fiddling around with my code I either get "undefined", "a page reload" or "an error in the console that my parameter used in the success function isn't defined"

Here's the ajax code:

```
function postComment(formdata) {
if (formdata.comment != '') {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../../includes/post_comment.php', 
        data: formdata,
        headers: {
            'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        },
        success: postSuccess(data), // function to handle the return
        error: postError // function to handle errors
    });
    } else {
        alert('Empty please write something!');
    }
}
function postSuccess(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#commentform').get(0).reset();
    displayComment(data);
}
```

and here is my PHP handler:

```
$ajax = ($_SERVER['REQUESTED_WITH'] === 'XMLHttpRequest');
$added = add_comment($mysqli, $_POST); // contains an array

if ($ajax) {
    sendAjaxResponse($added);
} else {
    sendStandardResponse($added);
}

function sendAjaxResponse($added)
{
    header("Content-Type: application/x-javascript");
    if ($added) {
        header('Status: 201');
        echo(json_encode($added));
     } else {
        header('Status: 400');
     }
}
```

this is what added looks like in PHP:

```
$added = array(
        'id' => $id,//integer example: 90
        'comment_post_ID' => $story_ID, //integer example: 21
        'comment_author' => $author, //String example: Dominic
        'comment' => $comment, //String example: This is a comment
        'comment_date' => $date); //DateTime/String example: 08/02/2016 1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

**UPDATES**

I changed the ajax code to the following:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../../includes/post_comment.php',
        success: postSuccess,
        data: formdata,
        headers: {
            'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        },
        error: postError,
    });
```

Now I get the full HTML-Code of the page calling this ajax function

I tried to set `aysnc: false` in the ajax request but it didn't help, always getting the html code of the source (calling the ajax function).

**As for now I´m moving to a different approach which doesn´t need the return data. But thanks for the help**

Comment: `../../includes/post_comment.php` is not an url

Comment: When you specify `success: postSuccess(data)` you are _calling_ `postSuccess` right away, with a non-existant `data` param.

Comment: Try removing `(data)`. The success param takes a function.  You are supplying the result of that function call to $.ajax

Comment: where is `postSuccess()`?

Comment: @TeKo sure it is...it's a relative url . Whether it's correct or not is not known

Comment: The url is correct and points to the php code I posted
@jszobody you mean sth like `success: function (data) { postSuccess(data); return data; }` ?

Comment: @Sartharon That would be one option, though you don't need the `return`. I'd just do `success: postSuccess` its simpler.

Comment: @jszobody using console.log and `success: postSuccess` gives me the ajax-calling php/html page (in it´s full html code) but shouldn´t it log the $added variable from my php code?

Comment: @Sartharon Dunno. You don't show what `$added` contains. You don't show your `postSuccess` function. Not much to go on.

Comment: @jszobody added the missing information sorry forgot to add the comment to `$added ..... // array`

Comment: `success: postSuccess(data)` that is very obviously incorrect given that postSuccess doesn't return a function when called.

Comment: at this point your server isn't returning what you think it should. it's a server problem or you are using the wrong url.

Comment: @KevinB i´m using the correct URL and do encode the echo from PHP as a result. My code is (in it´s full glory) presented as I´m stuck at not getting the result. Testing the PHP itself works the array is present and not empty

Comment: Yes, I see it, and it shouldn't be producing the results you are seeing, so something else is going on. we can't help.

Comment: weird, I´ll continue fiddling around with my code

Answer (score 0):

The browser tries execute server response because of

```
header("Content-Type: application/x-javascript");
```

change to

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Comment: Didn´t work either again the full HTML-code , but thanks

Comment: in the Ajax request is also necessary to specify the type of data: $.ajax({dataType: 'json',...

Comment: somehow get a parse error now  (console.log used in the error: function)even when i  `JSON.parse(formdata)`first any ideas ?

Comment: it is because you do not get json